# Evaluating values and returning coordinates in a 2d array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to program a method that would loop through a 2d array and return the coordinates of the elements that comply with a given condition (in this case, element value `== 1`):

```
def eval(array)
  array.each_index do |x|
    x.each_index do |y|
     if array[x][y] == 1 then 
      puts "X: #{x} Y: #{y}"
     end
   end
 end
end

array = [
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0]
]
eval(array)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
block in eval': undefined method `each_index' for 0:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

Any tips on what might be happening?

Comment: It's worth mentioning `eval` is not a good name for a function here as it conflicts with an existing method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array.each_index do |x|
```

captures this index into x variable and then you are trying to use each_index on number. Namely

```
x.each_index do |y|
```

Fixing this issue gives us the function:

```
def findMatchingCords(array)
  array.each_index do |x|
    array[x].each_index do |y|
     if array[x][y] == 1 then 
      puts "X: #{x} Y: #{y}"
     end
   end
 end
end
```

Now findMatchingCords(array) yields

```
X: 0 Y: 0
X: 1 Y: 1
X: 2 Y: 0
X: 2 Y: 3
X: 3 Y: 1
```

as expected.

Comment: Thank you! That definitely worked and I'm more aware now about what i'm I looping with these each and each_index loops. I'm taking into account the advise about changing my method name as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class.

```
require 'matrix'

def evaluate(array)  
  Matrix[*array].each_with_index { |e,x,y| puts "X: #{x} Y: #{y}" if e == 1 }
end

evaluate(array)
X: 0 Y: 0
X: 1 Y: 1
X: 2 Y: 0
X: 2 Y: 3
X: 3 Y: 1
```

Comment: Pretty useful this as well, thank you Cary. I rather use the other construction though as it looks more natural for me at the moment, I just begun with Ruby and I'm still not comfortable thinking in a so "rubysh" way.